# Update size and location of JavaFX stage not working

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm a beginner with JavaFX and I understand with swing/JFrames, there's the capacity to update the screen with the validate method. Does there exist an equivalent method in the JavaFX library for stages? When I perform a Thread.sleep() in the following code and update the size and location of the stage, the stage loads after the time has elapsed and then moves in an instant. This is not what I intended. I was hoping for the stage to load, wait the time, and then update the location and size. What's wrong here exactly? Thanks!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Driver extends Application
{    
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);      
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {             
        // Create the WebView
        WebView webView = new WebView();

        // Create the WebEngine
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        // LOad the Start-Page
        webEngine.load("https://www.reddit.com");

        // Update the stage title when a new web page title is available
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() 
        {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) 
            {
                if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) 
                {
                    //stage.setTitle(webEngine.getLocation());
                    stage.setTitle(webEngine.getTitle());
                }
            }
        });

        // Create the VBox
        VBox root = new VBox();

        // Add the WebView to the VBox
        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        // Create the Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        // Add  the Scene to the Stage
        stage.setWidth(200);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setX(500);
        stage.setY(500);
        stage.show();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        stage.setX(800);
        stage.setY(200);
        stage.setWidth(60);
        stage.setHeight(60);
   }
}
```

Comment: *with swing/JFrames, there's the capacity to update the screen with the validate method* - you should be using `revalidate()` with Swing. *When I perform a Thread.sleep()...* - well the same thing happens in Swing because you block the EDT and the GUI can't repaint itself. The solution in Swing is to use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the animation. I don't use JavaFx, but I would suggest you should be looking for the `Timer` equivalent in JavaFx, not the revalidate() equivalent.

Comment: @camickr Thanks but I'm trying to find a solution through JavaFX unfortunetley ;-(

Comment: I know you are using JavaFx, That is what my comment suggested. You can't find the appropriate class/method if you are looking in the wrong direction. I was attempting to point you in a different direction to look for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) should work.

> Replace:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
stage.setX(800);
stage.setY(200);
stage.setWidth(60);
stage.setHeight(60);
```

> With:

```
PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
wait.setOnFinished((e) -> {
    /*YOUR METHOD*/
    stage.setX(800);
    stage.setY(200);
    stage.setWidth(60);
    stage.setHeight(60);
});
wait.play();
```